# Перевод милисекунд в года

Tags: javascript

```
nowdate = new Date();
wardate = new Date();
var d = (nowdate.getFullYear() - wardate.setFullYear(1945)) / 1000 / 24 / 12;
document.write(d);
```

Мне нужен скрипт, который высчитывает сколько лет прошло с 1945 года. Переменная `d` принимает значение в миллисекундах, как перевести его в года?

Comment: Разделить на `31600800000`, очевидно же.

Comment: вот такой ответ выходит 24.523937354813803

Comment: Вообще это был саркастичный, но, тем не менее, почти правильный комментарий: `(new Date('2015-01-01').getTime() - new Date('1945-01-01').getTime())/31600800000 -> 69.90293916609706`. Смысл в том, что надо поделить получившееся число на количество миллисекунд в году, а его можно узнать как произведение `365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` (считаем, что у нас *равновисокосные* года).

Answer (score 1):

Зачем такие сложности?

```
d = nowdate.getFullYear() - 1945;
```

Comment: А кто дату будет сравнивать?
Время в годах - это скорее всего возраст же...

Comment: Топикстартер не устанавливает месяц и день. В этом случае данное решение корректно.